# bootstrap loading button state not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want my button to change to a loading state as per the boostrap documentation http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Why does my button not change to a loading state here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bootstrap Example</TITLE>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css ">
<STYLE>
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnD" data-loading-text="=)">hola!!!</button>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js "></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#btnD').click(function(){
                  var btn = $(this); 
                  btn.button('loading');
            });
        });
    </script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bootstrap URLs are not correct, no JS or CSS were loaded. These will work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bootstrap Example</TITLE>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<STYLE>
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnD" data-loading-text=":)">hola!!!</button>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#btnD').click(function(){
                  var btn = $(this); 
                  btn.button('loading');
            });
        });
    </script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The visual aspect of the button should change too.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to download the bootstrap css and js files in your machine. It works fine when the bootstrap css and js files are placed inline or link to css and js files placed in client machine. The Bootstrap css and js Urls are not valid one. Download Bootstrap css and js files [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/bootstrap.zip)